# What's wrong with the code on mysql

Tags: mysql

Very silly problem.
I am a beginner and trying to import it into MySQL but it does not work and tell me has an error near line 1.

```
CREATE TABLE `clown_info` (
 `name` varchar(50) default NULL,
 `last_seen` varchar(50) default NULL,
 `appearance` varchar(50) default NULL,
 `activities` varchar(50) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Elsie', 'Cherry Hill Senior Center', 'F, red hair, green dress, huge feet', 'balloons, little car');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Pickles', 'Jack Green\'s party', 'M, orange hair, blue suit, huge feet','mime');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Snuggles' ,'Ball?Mart' ,'F, yellow shirt, baggy red pants', 'horn, umbrella');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Mr. Hobo' ,'Party for Eric Gray' ,'M, cigar, black hair, tiny hat violin');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Clarabelle' ,'Belmont Senior Center' ,'F, pink hair, huge flower, blue dress', 'yelling, dancing');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Scooter', 'Oakland Hospital' ,'M, blue hair, red suit, huge nose', 'balloons'); 
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Zippo' ,'Millstone Mall', 'F, orange suit, baggy pants', 'dancing'); 
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Babe', 'Earl’s Autos' ,'F, all pink and sparkly', 'balancing, little car');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Bonzo' ,'','M, in drag, polka dotted dress', 'singing, dancing');
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Sniffles' ,'Tracy\'s', 'M, green and purple suit, pointy nose','');
```

Comment: Bring the full error message.

Comment: which line 1? you've got multiple queries there, each of which has its own line 1.

Comment: You're storing multiple values in a single column?  You also need to reconsider your database design

Comment: The 4th one only has 3 values, and your table has 4 columns.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: That's a little assumptious of you, the values may very well make perfect sense as just text. Just because there are commas doesn't mean it needs to be normalized.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Mr. Hobo' ,'Party for Eric Gray' ,'M, cigar, black hair, tiny hat violin');
```

**Column count doesn't match value count**

4 columns and 3 values being inserted.

Comment: It always seems to be Mr. Hobo that causes the trouble. Clowns... I tell ya, always somethin.

Answer (score 1):

The following `INSERT` line is failing:

```
INSERT INTO clown_info VALUES ('Mr. Hobo' ,'Party for Eric Gray' ,'M, cigar, black hair, tiny hat violin');
[Err] 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Your table has 4 columns, but the statement is only inserting 3.